# string indices must be integers in Json

Tags: python, json

I am getting an Error in the by me created JSON by the message: string indices must be integers. I did read some topics on stackoverflow about this issue, but it is not clear for me what I have to change.

The issue is with `items = json_data['items']`

My code:

```
    formattedUrl = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
    displayLink = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
    htmlFormattedUrl = ["https://stackoverflow.com/", "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page"]
    title = ["Stackoverflow", "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"]
    htmlTitle = ["Stackoverflow", "Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia"]
    snippet = ["Stack Overflow is the largest", "Main page"]

    #
    keys = ['formattedUrl', 'displayLink', 'htmlFormattedUrl', 'title', 'htmlTitle', 'snippet']
    items = [dict(zip(keys, [u, t, d, aa, ab, ac])) for u, t, d, aa, ab, ac in
             zip(formattedUrl, displayLink, htmlFormattedUrl, title, htmlTitle, snippet)]

    d = {

        'items': items
    }

    json_data = json.dumps(d, indent=4)


    #queries


    if has_result == 1 :
        # print "results"
        result = []
        results = []

        items = json_data['items']
```

Comment: When you do `json.dumps`, the dict `d` is converted into a json `str`, which is not a `dict` anymore. Just `items = d['items']` should give you what you need. Although, you already have the `items` at hand, why you are again putting it into a `dict` and getting it, i am not able to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, You need to use `json.loads` to bring it into right format(i.e., dictionary)

```
>>> data = json.loads(json_data)
>>> data['items']
'items' # your output
```