# Convert request.get and request.post data to dictionary

Tags: django, python-3.x

I'm trying to convert request.GET and request.POST to dictionary
I tried doing `request.GET.dict() and json.dumps(request.GET)`.
somehow it returns dict like structure. for eg: `{'name': 'abc'}`, but type of this dict is str

Comment: Try this `json.loads(your_json_data)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [string indices must be integers in Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58406964/string-indices-must-be-integers-in-json)

Comment: `request.GET` and `request.POST` are dict-like structures. Why do you want to convert these?

Comment: by default, it comes like querydict @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Jagerbomb: it is indeed a `QueryDict`, but that is a dict-like structure.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yeah, but can you help me with converting that query dict to actual dict

Comment: @Jagerbomb: but it is already a `dict`. The MRO is `(QueryDict, MutliValueDict, dict, object)`, so it is a *subclass* of `dict`.

Comment: query dict also returns value as list, for eg: ```<QueryDict: {'confidence': ['0.9']>```, my use case requires simple dict like ```{'confidence': '0.9'}``` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Jagerbomb: I think you are confusing *data* with the *representation* of data. By using a `JsonResponse` for example, you can represent the dictionary in a JSON blob, or whatever, but that does not make `request.GET` not a dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
data = {k:v[0] for k,v in dict(request.GET/POST)).items()}
```

Comment: Why are you using [0]? This won't work because you will get only the first char of the get/post value.

Comment: `dict(request.GET/POST)).items()` returns values of dict as list: {key: [value]}

Answer (score 3):

> I tried doing `request.GET.dict()` and `json.dumps(request.GET)`. somehow it returns dict like structure. for eg: `{'name': 'abc'}`, but type of this `dict` is `str`.

That makes perfect sense, since `json.dumps` makes a JSON blob. Such JSON blob is *always* a string. With this statement.

`request.GET` is however already a `dict`. Indeed, it is a [**`QueryDict`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/http/request.py#L391), and a `QueryDict` is a subclass of a [**`MultiValuedDict`** [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.2.x/django/utils/datastructures.py#L44). This is a subclass of the `dict`. So a `QueryDict` is a subclass of a `dict`.

You can obtain the dictionary by using the [**`QueryDict.dict()`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.dict) method, which will *return* a dictionary:

```
result = request.GET.dict()
```

and then for example create a JSON blob with that result:

```
json.dumps(request.GET.dict())
```

Here the last value in the querystring will be used if multiple ones are passed with the same key.

but that being said, usually it is not necessary to convert it to a dictionary in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

```py
get = dict(request.GET)
post = dict(request.POST)
```

But that is unnecessary.